# AWS - Metadata being set as lowercase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

So I have this issue that whenever I try to post a file to the s3 bucket with a pre-signed URL, the key for the metadata is being forced in lowercases?

I've looked at the Pre-signed URL it already sets the lowercase part when the URL has been genereted and Im wondering why? and how do I solve this issue?

I've tried to create a manual key-value pair in the s3 bucket on a file, where I clearly can set a key with capital letters as well?

```
   const params = {
        Bucket: 'buckets3',
        Key: 'hoho-fileUpload-' + uuid.v4(),
        Metadata: {"FooBar": "FooBar"},
        Expires: 600
    };
```

current output in the s3:

x-amz-meta-foobar: FooBar

Wishing output:

x-amz-meta-FooBar: FooBar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing you can do, AWS stores S3 metadata in lower case.

> User-defined metadata is a set of key-value pairs. Amazon S3 stores
>   user-defined metadata keys in lowercase.

From: [Object Meta Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata) and scroll to the bottom.  It's the paragraph just above the Note.

Answer (score 1):

On top of WaltDe's answered, I'd recommend you convert your metadata keys to kebab case when sending to aws s3 (foo-bar) so you can convert it back to pascal case in your lambda or code or wherever you use the metadata.